# Installing ocropus-0.4.4

Tags: python

I have installed ocropus-0.4.4 from installTranscirpt.When i run ocropus.py from ocroswig I get the following statments

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iulib.py", line 25, in <module>
    _iulib = swig_import_helper()
  File "iulib.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    import _iulib
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/_iulib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5iulib6dcloseEv
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to missing - or incorrectly versioned - binary system libraries. Try to build the package yourself, instead of grabbing a pre-built binary. The building process will give errors and say which libraries are missing, or in the incorrect version on your system. (You might have to install the aproppriate -dev or -devel Linux packages)

In the best case, it could only be an incompatibility between the pre-built binary and your system's, and if you have all the requisites, it could even build cleanly on the first try.