# ocropus installation on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python-2.7, shared-libraries, ocr, ubuntu-11.04

I need to install ocropus on Ubuntu 11.04.

I went through a long and painful process of trying ocropus 0.3 and 0.4 from the project's Downloads page, but to no avail - I could find no way of making it locate tesseract, which it recommended. I labored on Google and came across the page http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/wiki/InstallTranscript.

Great. Except when I issue the command:

```
hg clone $release https://ocropus.googlecode.com/hg/ ocropus
```

I get the error message:

```
abort: unknown revision 'ocropus-0.4.4'!
```

A post here http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=13444 by the maintainer of the ocropus package for archlinux says

> they have completely refactored ocropus and at the same time they have also completely removed the old repository so it's not possible to access the old "stable" versions. I suggest using the ocropus-hg package, at least for the time being.

I thought I would go ahead with this idea and issued the command:

```
hg clone https://ocropus.googlecode.com/hg/ ocropus #I deftly avoid any 
                                                              mention of the release
```

The result is I get a folder with a file interestingly named ocroinst. I run it and it says I need to run the following commands:

```
sudo ./ocroinst packages #checks the dependencies
./ocroinst install       #installs ocropus
sudo ./ocroinst dl       #downloads models
```

I was glad and I issued the first command, which is when I got the message:

> Package libjpeg8-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>   E: Package libjpeg8-dev has no installation candidate

I think a certain Murphy may have had a point.

The situation, with an delicious added complication, is this:

(please correct me if I am wrong)

1. Ubuntu 11.04 comes with libjpeg62-dev. The required version for ocropus is libjpeg8-dev.
2. Ocropus requires libtiff4-dev, and libtiff4-dev depends on libjpeg62-dev. Therefore there is no way for me to uninstall libjpeg62-dev.
3. libjpeg62-dev conflicts with libjpeg8-dev. Therefore, I can have only one of libjpeg8-dev or libjpeg62-dev, and never both.
4. If libjpeg8-dev is installed, I will have no libjpeg62-dev, which means I must remove libtiff4-dev and therefore have no way to install ocropus.
5. If libjpeg62-dev is installed, I will have no libjpeg8-dev and thus I will have no way to install ocropus.

**NOTE:**

(An experiment description)

I had libjpeg62-dev installed on the system already. I figured I could take a chance and I went right ahead and changed every libjpeg8-dev I could find to *libjpeg-dev*, and ran the 3 commands.

It installed. No error.

This gave me great joy
until
I ran the command

```
ocropus <image-file-name>
```

and I was greeted by the charming:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/_iulib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5iulib6dcloseEv
```

The more sophisticated

```
ocropus book2pages out image*
```

failed with the same error. A [post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134118/installing-ocropus-0-4-4)  indicates that this is caused by incorrectly versioned libraries.

**THE QUESTION:**

How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.